# Evenly distribute frequencies to canvas audio frequency analyzer

Tags: javascript

I have this analyzer (From a tutorial):

```
var playerE = document.getElementsByClassName('player')[0];;
var analyser = document.getElementById('analyzer');
var canvas, ctx, source, context, analyser, fbc_array, bars, bar_x, bar_width, bar_height;

window.addEventListener("load", playAnalyzer, false);

function playAnalyzer() {
    context = new AudioContext();
    analyser = context.createAnalyser();
    canvas = document.getElementById('analyzer');
    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    source = context.createMediaElementSource(playerE);
    source.connect(analyser);
    analyser.connect(context.destination);
    frameLooper();
}

function frameLooper() {
    canvas.width  = 800;
    canvas.height = 400;
    ctx.imageSmoothingEnabled = false;
    window.requestAnimationFrame(frameLooper);
    fbc_array = new Uint8Array(analyser.frequencyBinCount);
    analyser.getByteFrequencyData(fbc_array);
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height); // Clear the canvas
    ctx.fillStyle = "white"; // Color of the bars
    bars = 700;
    for (var i = 0; i < bars; i++) {
        bar_x = i * 5;
        bar_width = 3;
        bar_height = -(fbc_array[i] / 2);
        ctx.fillRect(bar_x, canvas.height, bar_width, bar_height);
    }
}
```

Now it works very nicely, the only problem I am facing is the frequencies. Since it's adding bars based on each frequency, when the width of the bars and the spacing is anything bigger than 1 the higher frequencies get left out. How can I evenly distribute the frequencies to the number of bars (bars=700) that is set?

I'd also like to know how can I add 2px in height in addition to the frequency volume? (So that the analyzer doesn't just dissapear when there isn't any sound)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out myself, here's how.

Since the for loop takes account for EVERY frequency, simply skip 4 bars every loop. Like so:

```
for (var i = 0; i < bars; i += 4) /*<-- Adding 4 instead of 1*/ {
        bar_x = i * 1;
        bar_width = 3;
        bar_height = -3 - (fbc_array[i] / 2);
        ctx.fillRect(bar_x, canvas.height, bar_width, bar_height);
    }
```

You will have to adjust the amount of bars, and the width and x. In order to offset the height on the bars, simply subtract whatever value from "bar-height" like shown. I am subtracting 3 in this example.

And that's it!